# Gather links in an Ajax page

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please go to this page : https://www.McMaster.com
Click on screws , in that page , there is no A tag for each item in the list but , if you right click on one of the you will see in your browser tools that the A tag will come up in the div of that item in the page ,

I'm using selenium and python and I want to gather all the *href*s of the A tags of the items in the list but they don't exist by default .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Internet Explorer (IE)? This website seems to have different code for IE and other browsers.

Try with Edge or Chrome browser

Comment: I use chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

**Dear,please use this code and will be working.**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.mcmaster.com/')
#empty list
all_links = []
#locate a tag
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for link in links:
    #All href links are save to the list
    all_links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
print(all_links)
```

Comment: I know it works for the first page :) go to screw page and there is no a tag in the items list by default